# How to display a count?

Tags: c#, count

I am in school doing an assignment and I am having trouble figuring out how to

```
 double[] marks = new double[10];
        marks[0] = 0;
        marks[1] = 0;
        marks[2] = 0;
        marks[3] = 0;
        marks[4] = 0;
        marks[5] = 0;
        marks[6] = 0;
        marks[7] = 0;
        marks[8] = 0;
        marks[9] = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter in 10 marks below: ");
        marks[0] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        marks[1] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        marks[2] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        marks[3] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        marks[4] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        marks[5] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        marks[6] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        marks[7] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        marks[8] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        marks[9] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        if (marks[9] >= 50)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\nYou Passed!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou ailed");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();`
```

I have gotten this far but I hit a road block trying to display the number count for many passed and how many failed.

Comment: Since you've studied arrays, you've certainly studied loops, right?

Comment: Yes, I literally just finished learning it

Comment: You should be good then, because arrays and loops go together like fries and ketchup :-)

Comment: Just realised it would make sense to use a loop XD

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i prefer chilly, instead :)), just for fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the array item and check the marks and update two counter variable, one for passed and one for failed.

```
var passedCount = 0;
var failedCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < marks.Length; i++)
{
    if (marks[i] >= 50)
    {
        passedCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        failedCount++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Passed count : "+ passedCount);
Console.WriteLine("Failed count : "+ failedCount);
```

Using LINQ, you can do it in a oneliner using the `Count` extension method.

```
var passedCount = marks.Count(a => a >= 50);
var failedCount = marks.Count(a => a < 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    double[] marks = new double[10];

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter in 10 marks below: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        marks[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("You passed {0} subjects.", marks.Where(mark => mark >= 50).Count());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `int counterPassed = 0` and `int counterFailed = 0`. Then inside the if else statement increment `counterPassed` and `counterFailed` by one. You can use either `counterPassed++` or `counterPassed += 1`. Then display it after the loop.

Comment: Thanks you helped a ton